# MBUnit - Calling the same method multiple times in a sequence?

Tags: methods, testing, mbunit

Is there a way in MBUnit to have the same test called multiple times with different parameters in a sequence, as such:

Method1()
Method2(param A)
Method3()
Method2(ParamB)
Method4()
Method2(ParamC)

etc? I've tried using the Order parameter but sadly I was too hopeful in that the Ordering would be considered class-wide rather than test-wide (1,2,3,4,5,6 as opposed to 1,2a,2b,2c,3,4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain the reasons for needing this? This sounds like you have dependencies between your test methods, which in general isn't a good way to go about writing test code.

If you need something to be called in a particular sequence then why not simply expose it as a single test method which calls certain submethods in the order of your choosing?

Comment: I'm building a test suite using WatiN to test common site usage habits on a website. I thought it would've been useful to have made a 'utility' method which fires a stopwatch, get the browser to move to a specific URL, and time the page load. Then I'd simply call this method instead of c&p'ing several lines every time I needed to go to a different page.

Anyway I think I've solved this using a StaticTestFactory. Have put some thought into removing dependancy but I'm not too big on C&P'ing code which would be used in several test classes, but it seems like I'll have to do it.

Comment: My general suggestion for writing web test code (using WatiN, Selenium or similar) is to use the PageObjects pattern (http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects), this will help you minimize any c&p and make the code more manageable.

Comment: Thank you very much, that pattern is a brilliant idea.